# focus() on input that is inside hidden div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use `focus()` on an input that is inside a hidden div using

```
opacity: 0; 
visibility: hidden;
```

and on the click of a button, the div becomes visible through a new class added to the body:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yyd1pgaa/

If I remove the transition effects, the `focus()` works, so I'm guessing browsers can't focus on something that isn't 100% visible yet?

And is it possible without having to use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Just wondering why not just use opacity 0 then go opacity 1 on click. Why not just use visibility?

Comment: Because elements that only have opacity: 0 are clickable, elements that also have visibility:hidden makes them not ciickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only transition `opacity` here it will work.

For example:

```
transition: 0.5s opacity ease;
```

Updated jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/b6025bc7/